# Footer not sticking to bottom of certain pages

Tags: css

The following snippet of code makes most of my pages stick to the bottom but the ones that don't are sub-menu items and have a contact form with captcha inside of them. I am unsure what is causing this, please can you help?

```
#sub-footer {
    background: #222;
    border-top: 1px solid #444;
    padding: 15px 0px;
    width: 100%;
    bottom: 0px;
    position:absolute;
    left:0px;
}
```

This is from my website, on the following link you can see it in action: ingenuous.web44.net/products/basic

Comment: we will need more code or fiddle trying to reproduce the issue

Comment: Indeed, please post your html.

Comment: Sorry for the lack of code. Why bit would you like?

Comment: once i take out the contact form on this page that is beneath some text it seems to stick to the bottom again..

Comment: Post one of the pages that's having the issue

Answer (score 0):

Remove `bottom: 0px;` from your code, you will find your desired output.

Comment: Thank you! :) I would one-up your comment but i do not have enough reputation, sorry! 

How come having that made my website not look how i wanted it too?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't post your entire code so I am not more clear about your problem, but according to my guess this is just because of the height of your other contents which are taller than the window height, which you already made your footer to be `position: absolute;` and stick it to the `bottom: 0` which will make your footer to stick on the bottom of your window height. If thats the case you can clearly remove your `bottom:0` from your style.

Note: If your contents other than the footer are shorter in the other pages which will not fit your footer to your bottom of the page. Hence have different styles according to your needs.